# Exporting to CSV from complex rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, fastercsv

I was following this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) video but I'm having serious difficulties to export my data to excel (or CSV for this matter).

I'm using will_paginate in some data that I show on frontend like this:

```
sql = "select complex..."
@data = paginate_by_sql([sql],
                :per_page => params[:rows],
                :page => params[:page])
```

so, as is, I thought this should work:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xls { send_data @data.to_csv(:col_sep => "\t") }
end
```

and it actually downloaded a xls file correctly by the content is all messed up, it shows one row per column and something like this as content:

`#<Product:0x00000004c83328>`

PS -> using rails latest version

:: EDIT ::
By one row per column I mean one row only on my excel sheet and on this row

COLUMN A = `#<Product:0x00000004c83328>`

COLUMN B = `#<Product:0x00000004c83329>`

COLUMN C = `#<Product:0x00000004c8333>` (30 columns)

**UPDATE**

Did a simple exercise for testing and end up with all columns again in one column only:

```
csv_string = CSV.generate(:col_sep => ",") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
end

respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data csv_string,
        :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
        :disposition => "attachment; filename=records.csv" }
end
```

`(:col_sep => ",")` is optional I suppose.

result:

[image: excel output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so this is what I did.

modified the responder to this...

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.xls
end
```

and created a template called nameofmethod.xls.erb with this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
      <% @data.first.attributes.keys.each do |column| %>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%=column%></Data></Cell>
      <% end %>
      </Row>
    <% @data.each do |row| %>
      <Row>
      <% row.attributes.values.each do |column| %>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= column %></Data></Cell>
      <% end %>
      </Row>
    <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

This is pretty dynamic for any kind of ActiveRecord Object. 
For now this will have to do...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to map each of your `Product` model objects because you are calling `to_s` on them, which is undefined.

So if you just want a list of titles, you could override the `to_s` method on your model (`app/models/product.rb`) to do something like:

```
def to_s
  title
end
```

Or, to generate a comma separated list you could do

```
def to_s
  [title, price, availability].join(',')
end
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand what you mean by me calling a `to_s`...I'm just calling `paginate_by_sql`. Although I realize the output seems like model converted to string... it's strange alright. I must be close...

Comment: Yes, if you call to_s on a model, like `Person` you will get output like `#<Product:0x00000004c83329>`.  Which is the default string conversion for an ActiveRecord Model.  So, i'm suggesting you override this method in your model by defining a new `to_s` method.

Answer (score 0):

You might use this gem, you can export any complex query easily.

https://github.com/stevenbarragan/julia_builder